# Error on cart and checkout In magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, post-data

I am just testing magento2 from product page so i added one hidden field and added data URI of image like following

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABU
```

But when i go to the cart or checkout page it give me error due to this! Is there any issue passing huge data from product page. Following is error

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 199 of 65535 bytes in C:\wamp\www\m2learn\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\CustomOptions\CustomOptionProcessor.php on line 100 .
```

**Note:** I am not setting any custom option. I have cleared cache and generation folder. Might be due to post data is huge.

Comment: this error  is dues to invalid serialization data due to invalid length. Please check your data is generated in proper serialize format.

Comment: As i said i am not serializing anything on my product page. It is just simple data URI of image which i tested on magento1 and it is working fine.